# How can I create rolling sum after ignoring value at current time step?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe

```
year      t  
19620101    1
19630102    2   
19640103    3   
19650104    4   
19650104    5   
19650104    6
```

And the expected output is this:

```
 year      t  t2 t3
19620101    1   NA  NA
19630102    2   NA   NA
19640103    3   3   NA
19650104    4   5   6
19650104    5   7   9
19650104    6   9  12
```

Currently, I am using this inside a function

```
Accum<-function(df,lag){
setDT(df)[, paste0(t, 2:lag) := lapply(2:lag, function(x) 
     rollsum(df[[t]], x, na.pad = TRUE, align='right'))]
}
Accum(df=dat,lag=4)
```

And I get this output

```
year      t    t2   t3
19620101    1   NA  NA
19630102    2   3  NA
19640103    3   5   6
19650104    4   7   9
19650104    5   9   12
19650104    6   11   15
```

But how can I ignore the value at current time step before doing the rolling sum? And I should be able to use it inside a function so that I can do it over and over again.

Comment: arent you already getting what you want in the expected output?

Comment: Oops, Sorry. Could you please see again

Comment: Try applying your rolling sum function to `t[ , !is.na(t2)]` or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t<-seq(1:10)


myfun <- function(t){
  lt <- length(t)
  t2<-rep(NA, lt)
  t2 <-rep(NA, lt)

  for(i in 3:lt){
    t2[i] <- t[i-1]+ t[i-2]
    }
  for(i in 4:lt){
    t3[i] <- t[i-1] + t2[i-1]
    }
  result <- cbind(t,t2,t3)
  return(result)
}
```